# AngularJS - Custom Directive ng-click not working (External Template with ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

have a problem with my AngularJS code, I am currently trying to fill my sidebar with `<li>s` that have `<a>s` inside, with ng-click to call a function inside a controller.

**So the problem is that the after I succesfuly load the directive, the ng-click inside that directive does not work.**

Im new to Angular so im sorry if I made any stupid mistake.

So my **HTML** is:

```
<body ng-Controller="myController as ctrl">
  <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <sidebar-items recieved-items="ctrl.recievedSidebar" item-click="ctrl.getItems(&quot;{{ctrl.recievedSidebar.name}}&quot;)">
    </sidebar-items>
  </ul>
</body>
```

My **Angular app** is:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', myController)
.service('getItemsService', getItemsService)
.directive('foundItems', FoundItemsDirective)
.directive('sidebarItems', SideBarItemsDirective)

myController.$inject = ['getItemsService'];
function myController(getItemsService) {
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.title = "title";
  ctrl.recieved = undefined;
  ctrl.getItems = function (jsonFile) {    
    getItemsService.getItems(jsonFile)
    .then(function (result) {
      if (jsonFile == "Collections"){
        ctrl.recievedSidebar = result.Collections;
      }else {
        ctrl.recieved = result.links;
        ctrl.title = "Title"
      }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Something went wrong!!! Error code = " + error);
    });

  }
  ctrl.getItems("Collections");
  ctrl.notRecieved = function () {
    if (ctrl.recieved == undefined) {
      return false;
    }
    return ctrl.recieved.length == 0;
  }


}


getItemsService.$inject = ['$http'];
function getItemsService($http) {
  var service = this;
  service.getItems = function(jsonFile) {
    return $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: ("json/" + jsonFile + ".json"),
      cache: true
    }).then(function(response){
      return response.data;
    });
  }
}


function FoundItemsDirective() {
  var ddo = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'directiveTemplates/foundItemsDirective.html',
        scope: {
            items: '<recievedItems'
        },
        controller: DirectiveController,
        controllerAs: 'dirCtrl',
        bindToController: true,
        transclude: true
        };
    return ddo;
  };


function DirectiveController() {

}

function SideBarItemsDirective() {
  var ddo = {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'directiveTemplates/sideBarDirectiveTemplate.html',
    scope: {
      items: '<recievedItems',
      itemClick: '&'
    },
    controller: SideBarDirectiveController,
    controllerAs: 'dirCtrl',
    bindToController: true,
    transclude: true
    };
    return ddo;
  }
function SideBarDirectiveController() {

}

})();
```

And my **Directive template** is:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in dirCtrl.items">
  <a href="" ng-click="ctrl.getItems(&quot;{{item.name}}&quot;)">{{item.label}}</a>
</li>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your ng-click expression with ctrl.getItems() you can just pass the item.name directly like this ctrl.getItems(item.name)